# VS2012 Coded UI Tests: can't run. References, path required?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I'm trying to run a Coded UI Test from within VS2012.

I've built a Coded UI Test Project.

I can run it from MSTest at the command line

```
mstest /testcontainer:C:\projects\Chilli\bin\Debug\Test.Desktop.UI.dll
```

When I try to run from within VS2012 I'm getting "Could not load file or assembly '...Playback.dll'"

...as soon as I call Playback.Initialize()

I'm running VS2012 as administrator.
My path includes C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE, \PublicAssemblies and \PrivateAssemblies and these are also included in the project Reference Paths.

Is there anywhere else I can specify where to look for DLLs? Thanks! nick

Comment: it turns out that in Coded UI Tests, it is very time consuming to update and query DataGrids in wpf. I think I will give up on Coded UI Tests and try to get more out of testing the ViewModel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `setx` by cmd so u can set your path, [more info here](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)

https://serverfault.com/questions/465924/windows-how-do-i-add-a-program-to-the-systems-path-environmental-variable-from

Comment: Could you please add some more info from the provided link? I accidently assumed this was spam. Thanks :)

Comment: That sounds like it will set the Path environment variable, which I've already done... but I will mark it as the answer, thanks for taking an interest!

Comment: @PranavKapoor웃 hey dude don't worry it's not a spam
http://serverfault.com/questions/465924/windows-how-do-i-add-a-program-to-the-systems-path-environmental-variable-from

Comment: @ajd i've recently had the same problem u're having and i solved it this way i've put a new link i hope u find it useful